# Datediff issue - PHP,Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datediff

So in my database i've got **regdate** (date type), but no matter what date it is, the code keeps returning 1.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
$row = $result->fetch_array();

$date1 = new DateTime($row['regdate']);
$date2 = new DateTime("now");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "It has been " .$interval->d." days ";
//$interval is supposed to be difference between regdate and todays date
```

I hope I'm not missing something stupid. Thank you for your anwers.

**SOLVED**

Comment: so what's supposed to be the correct output?

Comment: `echo $row['regdate'];` i bet you its not what you expect

Comment: @Ghost difference between their regdate and todays date

Comment: there's your hint from Dagon

Comment: @Dagon Sorry, I'm not from english speaking country so I don't know what do you mean by that :/

Comment: Guys I'm so sorry for this stupid question, didn't noticed that. Gonna get some sleep, thank you all for answers.

Answer (score 1):

I belive this might be more easier.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),$row['regdate']);
```

and I think you need a while loop to find all the records.